# Why won't JSFiddle print this object?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm trying to experiment with object in Angular.

I'm using JSFiddle to declare some JSON objects in an Angular controller but it's not working and I can't figure out why not. Some someone with fresh eyes or more complete brain take a look and tell me why?

[JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/11059/)

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = {
        "countries": {
            "usa": "washington",
                "canada": "ottawa",
                "netherlands": [
                "official": "amsterdam",
                "administrative": "The Hague"],
                "israel": "jerusalem"
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, as Quentin pointed out that I was confusing Arrays and Objects (not really, I do know the difference, but I was making a silly mistake).

Specifically, in the code above, I used `key:value` notation inside the array for `netherlands`. It should have read

```
        "netherlands": [
            {"official": "amsterdam"},
            {"administrative": "The Hague"}
        ],
```

Answer (score 5):

Read your JavaScript console

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

You are confusing [objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Object_literals) `{}` and [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Array_literals) `[]`.